# How to solve the equation $x^2-ny^2$ with $n>0$ and $p$ prime in integers?

Tags: number-theory

I often see the equation $x^2+ny^2=p$ discussed where $n$ is a positive integer and $p$ is a prime.

What about a negative value of $n$, particularly the equation $x^2-3y^2=p$?

Comment: See equation $(5)$ in this link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html

Comment: Thank you. This is useful.

Answer (score 2):

When $n$ is positive there is an obvious fact: there are only finitely many pairs of integers $(x,y)$ which are solutions of the equation. This still leaves plenty of interesting number theoretic questions to pursue, such as: if we fix a positive value of $n$, how does the number of solutions of the equation vary for different values of $p$?

But while the question of finitely many versus infinitely many solutions is obvious for positive $n$, it is *not at all* obvious for negative numbers $n = -m$ ($m>0$): Do there exist infinitely many solutions to $x^2 - m y^2 = p$? Is there some interesting number theoretic structure to these solution sets? The answers are "yes" and "yes", and these topics are studied more fully in the Dirichlet units theorem.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite book for this material is Binary Quadratic Forms by Duncan A. Buell. Published about 1989 I think.

$x^2 - 3 y^2 = p$ is always possible for (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod {12}.$ If you know how to solve $u^2 \equiv 3 \pmod p$ there is a fairly quick method to find relevant $x,y.$

Well, why not. In this first case, find even $b$ such that $b^2 \equiv 12 \pmod {4p},$ or $b^2 = 12 + 4pt.$ Then the binary quadratic form with coefficients $\langle p,b,t \rangle$ (meaning $pu^2 + b uv + t v^2$) has discriminant 12. Gauss-Lagrange-Legendre reduction for indefinite forms takes this to $\langle 1,2,-2 \rangle, \; $ and careful accounting along the way allows a reversal, which includes a solution to $r^2 + 2rs-2s^2 = p.$ But this is just $(r+s)^2 - 3 s^2 = p.$

$x^2 - 3 y^2 = -p$ is always possible for (positive) prime $p \equiv 11 \pmod {12}$ as well as $p=2,3. \; \;$ If you know how to solve $u^2 \equiv 3 \pmod p$ there is a fairly quick method to find relevant $x,y.$

===========================================================

```
           1           0          -3   original form 

 Represented (positive) primes up to  1000

    13    37    61    73    97   109   157   181   193   229
   241   277   313   337   349   373   397   409   421   433
   457   541   577   601   613   661   673   709   733   757
   769   829   853   877   937   997

 these are the collection of remainders when dividing by   12

      1
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
          -1           0           3   original form 

 Represented (positive) primes up to  1000

     2     3    11    23    47    59    71    83   107   131
   167   179   191   227   239   251   263   311   347   359
   383   419   431   443   467   479   491   503   563   587
   599   647   659   683   719   743   827   839   863   887
   911   947   971   983

 these are the collection of remainders when dividing by   12

      2      3     11
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

We get an answer based entirely on simple congruences because there is one form per genus in this discriminant. The form class number is two, while the field class number is one, in the number field viewpoint $f$ and $-f$ are identified.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle_All_Reduced 12


Sun Feb 17 08:27:03 PST 2019


12    factored   2^2 *  3

    1.             1           2          -2   cycle length             2
    2.            -1           2           2   cycle length             2
    3.             2           2          -1   cycle length             2
    4.            -2           2           1   cycle length             2


12    factored   2^2 *  3

    1.             1           2          -2   cycle length             2
    2.            -1           2           2   cycle length             2

  form class number is   2

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed!